# Как вывести данные WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Я хочу вывести данные из масива в checkbox, но никак не могу привести до определёного типа чтобы вывести

XAML

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyProperty}" Margin="0"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <dxe:CheckEdit Content="{Binding FilePath}" Padding="2.5" Margin="3" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"  />

            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

C#

```
   public List<DataText> list;

    private ObservableCollection<MyCheckBox> Items = new ObservableCollection<MyCheckBox>();

    public ICollectionView ItemsView { get; set; }

    public TextViewModel()
    {

        Items.Add(new MyCheckBox { FilePath = "Debug.txt", IsChecked = false });
        Items.Add(new MyCheckBox { FilePath = "Info", IsChecked = false });
        Items.Add(new MyCheckBox { FilePath = "Error", IsChecked = false });
        Items.Add(new MyCheckBox { FilePath = "Fatal", IsChecked = true });
        Items.Add(new MyCheckBox { FilePath = "Fine", IsChecked = true });
        Items.Add(new MyCheckBox { FilePath = "Finer", IsChecked = true });
        Items.Add(new MyCheckBox { FilePath = "Finest", IsChecked = true });
        Items.Add(new MyCheckBox { FilePath = "Warn", IsChecked = true });

        ItemsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Items);


        list = new List<DataText>();
    }
    IEnumerable<DataText> blabal;

    public IEnumerable<DataText> MyProperty
    {
        get
        { return list.Where(x => ItemsView.Contains(x.TypeFiles)); }
        set { blabal= value;
        OnPropertyChange("MyProperty");
        }

    }



    #region Command

    private RelayCommand _openCommand;

    public ICommand OpenCommand
    {
        get { return _openCommand = new RelayCommand(param => OpenDial(), param => CanOpen); }
    }

    private void OpenDial()
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog fb = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        DialogResult result = fb.ShowDialog();

        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(fb.SelectedPath); // папка с файлами
        var files = new List<string>(); // список для имен файлов

        var temp = dir.GetFiles("*.txt.*");

        foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles("*.txt.*")) // извлекаем все файлы и кидаем их в список
        {
            // files.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FullName));// получаем полный путь к файлу и потом вычищаем ненужное, оставляем только имя файла.
            files.Add(Path.GetFileName(file.FullName));
        }

        list = ReadTextFile.LoadDateListFromFile(files);

             var newList = list.Where(x => ItemsView.Contains(x.TypeFiles));


        MyProperty = newList;

        DataT = list;

    }
```

Как мне связать данные? Ничего не выводится.

вот примерно так должен виглядеть фильтр

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример данных, и пример того, как должен выглядеть результат (какая строка должна вывестись).

Comment: Должно вивестись всё что есть ItemsView, если оно есть в list, тоесть если ститать сфайлов debug.txt, info.txt, error.txt, то должно вивести checkEdit debug, info, error чтобы, можно было потом отфильтровать их

Comment: А можете привести конкретный пример?

Comment: У вас в xaml  ItemsSource="{Binding MyProperty}", что является коллекцией DataText, но далее вы завязываетесь на св-ва MyCheckBox.

Comment: и не совсем понятно зачем здесь прослойка в виде ICollectionView

Comment: это для фильтра

Comment: Для фильтра вам нужно байндить коллекцию на ItemsView, у которой есть инструменты для фильтрации https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.filter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: да но данные я беру из файлов, а фильтр нужно сделать по файлах

Comment: Добавьте в MyCheckBox св-во MyData, которое будет заполнятся данными из файла и добавьте соответствующий байндинг в xaml

Comment: не делает, в МуData виходит не одно поле, а дата, опис и еще тип файла по какому нужно фильтровать, может как-то по другому можно ?

Comment: Так добавьте поля, которые надо отображать в соотв. св-ва `MyCheckBox { MyData, Date, Description, Type }`

Comment: `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsView}" Margin="0"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate><TextBox Text={Binding MyData}/><TextBox Text={Binding Date}/><TextBox Text={Binding Description}/><TextBox Text={Binding Type}/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>`